# foundation : Unable to work over modal's event (Input, Button) , If the Page is not just reloaded

Tags: typescript, zurb-foundation, angular9

I am working on an angular project currently with version 9. I am using Foundation here.

I added a foundation modal in my website. It works properly only just after reloading the page, once I leave the current page and go back to the same page. input's and button's functionality inside the modal doesn't work. so it happens after navigation or going back to another page, then come again to the page, modal's events can't be update or I am unable to call any function on any event.

.html

```
<div data-open="myModal">Remove</div>
<div id="myModal" class="reveal" data-reveal aria-hidden="true">
    <H4>Are you sure you want to remove it?</H4>
    <button class="close-reveal-modal button" data-close aria-label="Close modal" 
    (click)="modalFunction()">Confirm</button>

    <button class="close-button closeModal" data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

.ts

```
modalFunction() {
    console.log('button inside modal is working');
}
```

In this code above, in output I get result in console only when the page is refreshed or it is open first time after reloading the website. Once I go back / navigating to another page and then go back to the same page, It doesn't print result in console.
Please check it out. If anyone have any solution or suggestion for this.Please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a stackblitz demo (if possible) where I/we can reproduce a same issue!

Comment: that won't help you to understand the problem. because my problem doesn't appear after refreshing the page. and chrome every time reloads the page if we click on back button or forward button.

Comment: believe me, it will help. Otherwise it will become bit more hard to help you!